# mysql command line generate 2 files from 1 source

Tags: mysql, command-line

If I would like to generate 2 files(same data,same file name but different path) How can I do this?

Here is my code

```
mysql -h -u -p -e "select * from customer" prdb> D:\patha.txt
mysql -h -u -p -e "select * from customer" prdb> C:\patha.txt
```

Please suggest if there is a better way to do.

Comment: Simply _copy_ the first file into the second location, instead of running the MySQL export twice …?

Comment: I need to place these 2 file at 2 different server and these huge files. I would like to find another solution that generate one time and create 2 files and then pass into seperate path. By the way, may be the simply copy as your suggest is the way that I have to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: _“I need to place these 2 file at 2 different server and these huge files”_ - then perhaps `rsync` would be the better choice (than copy), that usually performs best when it comes to server-to-server data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a use case for `tee` if you have Powershell (you're on Windows I suppose) available. It works like this:

```
echo "query result" | tee fileC fileD
```

For the docs of `tee` in Powershell, see [here](https://ss64.com/ps/tee-object.html).

Comment: The error showned tee is not recognized as an interanal or external command.

Comment: Hm, are you using Powershell?!

Comment: Ok, then `tee` is not available of course. Maybe you can consider using Powershell or you just copy the file as mentioned before.